# How to copy a Folder Iterative in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, vb.net-2010

i created a program that copies folders + content into a different location, but this doesn't work with Folders in sizes i work with (50GB). I currently have a recursive function but it seems that this exceeds the memory limits. The only solution I could think of by now was a CMD call like.

```
process.start("cmd", "/C xcopy /E /V /I /Y """ & srcfld & """ """ & targfld & """")
```

Please excuse my variable-names, I'm lazy when it comes to typing names.

EDIT: The requested function:

```
Public Sub ordkop(ByVal srcfld As String, ByVal targfld As String)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(targfld)
    Dim files() As String
    files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(srcfld)
    For Each element As String In files
        If Directory.Exists(element) Then
            CopyDir(element, Path.Combine(targfld, Path.GetFileName(element)))
        Else
            File.Copy(element, Path.Combine(targfld, Path.GetFileName(element)), True)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your function, might be able to help a little better if we can see the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps [`Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383358(v=vs.110).aspx) would work better for you than `Directory.GetFileSystemEntries`.

Comment: a bit more files are copied but still far away from 50GB